Product of expectation one almost surely positive
Suppose I have two random variables $X$ and $Y$
I know two things :
$X \geq 0$ almost surely
$\operatorname{E}(XY) \geq 0$
Can I say that $\operatorname{E}(Y) \geq 0$ ?
I would like to say yes but I am not sure and I do not manage to prove it.
Any help ? Thanks.

Well, no.  If $X$ is identically $0$, then any $Y$ satisfies $E[XY]=0$.  Easy to design less degenerate examples if you prefer.

Take $\Omega=\{\omega_1,\omega_2\}$ and equip it with the discrete uniform distribution, so $P(\omega_1)=P(\omega_2)=\frac{1}{2}$, then define:
$X,Y:\Omega \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$
\begin{gather}X(\omega_1)=9, \ X(\omega_2)=0 \\
Y(\omega_1)=0, \ Y(\omega_2)=-9 
\end{gather}
Then $P(X\geq 0)=1$, $\mathbb{E}(XY)=0$, but $\mathbb{E}(Y)=- \frac{9}{2}$.

Thanks for your answer

Even if we require $X > 0$ strictly, this is not true. Suppose that $(X, Y) \in \{(1, -10), (4, 4)\}$ with probability $1/2$ each. Then $E(XY) = 3 > 0$ but $E(Y) = -3 < 0$.

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)$, so if $E(XY) \geq 0$, $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$ cannot have opposite sign. Thus, if $E(X) > 0$ strictly, then yes, $E(Y) \geq 0$. But if $E(X) = 0$, then $E(Y)$ could be negative.
